# TensorFlow Docker -- Cannot find mounted drive

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am running the TensorFlow GPU docker image found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingDocker

I am running this on Ubuntu.

I am new to docker containers and I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to make my Jupyter Notebook see the harddrives I have mounted to the host machine.

Comment: What operating system are we talking about here? Do you want to mount a hard drive or a file system path?

Comment: I am running this on Ubuntu 14.

I have three hard drives mounted to /home/media/user but when I run python inside of the docker container, it cannot find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the docker run command you need to include the -v or --volume parameter.

For example:

```
docker run -it -v /home/media/user:/tmp/media -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu bash
```

Then you will find those files in /tmp/media of the docker container.